# Java "tail -f" wrapper

Tags: java, unix, tail

I need to wrap the Unix command "tail -f" in a BufferedInputStream.  I don't want to simulate or mimic tail as stated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557844/java-io-implementation-of-unix-linux-tail-f).  Rather, I want to use tail, waiting for it to give me a new line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the `Process` class and read with a `Scanner`:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime()
Process p = r.exec("tail -f")
Scanner s = new Scanner(p.getInputStream())
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = s.nextLine()
    // Do whatever you want with the output.
}
```

`hasNextLine()` should block as it's waiting for more input from the input stream, so you will not be busy-waiting as data comes in.

Comment: The only problem is that it requires a new line character at the end

Answer (score 1):

Look at Runtime.exec(String command).  Returns a **Process** object that has Input and Output Streams.

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for. I'll be trying this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check also [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

```
Process tail = new ProcessBuilder("tail", "-f", file).start();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(tail.getInputStream())
```

where `file` is String like "/var/log/messages".

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that system() and popen() type approaches will not work as they will block your program until the tail command terminates.

I think you could redirect the output to a file and use 'diff' against the last version to see which lines are new?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the unix command

```
tail -f <file> | <some java program>
```

Then the tail would appear as an `InputStream` that may block for a period of time.  If you don't want to block yourself, you would use the nio packages.  I believe that most other ways to access the tail command (such as `Process`) results in a similar `InputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Two more full blown projects:

http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/gla/gettingstarted_gla.html

http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html