# Detecting RollOver files in Java

Tags: file, rollover, java-io

I am listening changes to a syslog file in Java. I use [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557844/java-io-implementation-of-unix-linux-tail-f) to process new entries to the file. However, I couldnt find an efficient solution for detecting rollover files. Syslog file might be rolledover daily or based on filesize.

What are the best practises for handling such a case?