# parse an active log file

Tags: parsing, logging

Looking for a little help getting started on a little project i've had in the back of my mind for a while.

I have log file(s) varying in size depending on how often they are cleaned from 50-500MB. I'd like to write a program that will monitor the log file while its actively being written to.  when in use it's being changed pretty quickly easily several hundred lines a second or so.  Most if not all of the examples i've seen for reading log/text files are simply open and read file contents into a variable which isn't really feasible to do every time the file changes in this situation.   I've not settled on a language to write this in but its on a windows box and I can work in .net flavors / java / or php ( heh dont think php will fly to well for this), and can likely muddle through another language if someone has a suggestion for something well built for handling this.

Essentially I believe what I'm looking for would probably be better described to as a high speed way of monitoring a text file for changes and seeing what those changes are.  Each line written is relatively small. (less than 300 characters, so its not big data on each line).

EDIT: to change the wording to hopefully better describe what i'm trying to do.  Which is write a program to keep an eye on a log file for a trigger then match a following action to that trigger.  So my question here is pertaining to file handling inside a programming language.

I greatly appreciate any thoughts/comments.

Comment: Have you considered a tool like BareTail? http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/

Comment: I like the looks of that for other uses, but for this I need to act on a trigger in the log file and then monitor for an action that should follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's incremental then you can just read the whole file the first time you start analyzing logs, then you keep the current size as *n*. Next time you check (maybe a timed action to check last modified date) just skip first *n* bytes, read all new bytes and update size.

Otherwise you could use `tail -f` by getting its stdout and using it for your purposes..

Answer (score 0):

The 'keep an eye on a log file' part of what you are describing is what `tail` does.

If you plan to implement it in Java, you can check this question: [Java IO implementation of unix/linux "tail -f"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557844/java-io-implementation-of-unix-linux-tail-f) and add your trigger logic to lines read.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not reinventing the wheel.
Try using the [elastic.co](https://www.elastic.co/products)

[image]

All of these applications are open source and free and are capable of monitoring (together) and trigger actions based on input.

**filebeats** - will read the log file line by line (supports multiline log messages as well) and will send it across to logstash. There are loads of other shippers you can use.

**logstash** - will take the log messages, filter them, add tags and send the messages to elasticsearch

**elasticsearch** - will take the log messages and index them, the store them. It is also capable of running actions based on input

**kibana** -  is a user friendly web interface to query and analyze the data. Or just simply put it up on a dashboard.

Hope this helps.