# Monitoring file changes

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to monitor the file content and adding any new line to JTextArea. I created thread, which monitor the file, but when the Scanner object reachs the end of file it stop working. I tried very simple method, which create new Scanner object and read the file from the begin, but it isn't good solution. 
It's the version which stop and do nothing :

```
public class TextAreaThread implements Runnable {

JTextArea text = null;
File file = null;
Scanner read = null;

public TextAreaThread(JTextArea text, File file) {
    this.text = text;
    this.file = file;
    try{
        read = new Scanner(file);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong file or file doesn't exist","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}

public void run() { 

    while(true){
        while(read.hasNext())
                text.append(read.nextLine()+"\n");
        try {
            wait(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}


}
```

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: What's the question? Where's the code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java IO implementation of unix/linux "tail -f"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557844/java-io-implementation-of-unix-linux-tail-f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wait` method is not what you want here. Try `Thread.sleep` instead.