# Tail a file in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am wondering is there is a simple way to tail a file in Groovy? I know how to read a file, but how do I read a file and then wait for more lines to be added, read them, wait, etc...

I have what I am sure is a really stupid solution:

```
def lNum = 0
def num= 0
def numLines = 0
def myFile = new File("foo.txt")
def origNumLines = myFile.eachLine { num++ }
def precIndex = origNumLines

while (true) {
num = 0
lNum = 0
numLines = myFile.eachLine { num++ }

if (numLines > origNumLines) {
    myFile.eachLine({ line ->

    if (lNum > precIndex) {
            println line
        }
    lNum++
    })
}
precIndex = numLines

 Thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

Note that I am not really interested in invoking the Unix "tail" command. Unless it is the only solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557844/java-io-implementation-of-unix-linux-tail-f

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wrote a groovy class which resembles the basic tail functionality:

```
class TailReader {

  boolean stop = false

  public void stop () {
    stop = true
  }

  public void tail (File file, Closure c) {
    def runnable = {
     def reader

      try {
        reader = file.newReader()
        reader.skip(file.length())

        def line

        while (!stop) {
          line = reader.readLine()
          if (line) {
            c.call(line)
          }
          else {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000)
          }
        }

      }
      finally {
        reader?.close()
      }
    } as Runnable

    def t = new Thread(runnable)
    t.start()
  }
}
```

The `tail` method taks a file and closure as parameters. It will run in a separate thread and will pass each new line that will be appended to the file to the given closure. The `tail` method will run until the `stop` method is called on the `TailReader` instance. Here's a short example of how to use the `TailReader` class:

```
def reader = new TailReader()
reader.tail(new File("/tmp/foo.log")) { println it }

// Do something else, e.g. 
// Thread.currentThread().sleep(30 * 1000)

reader.stop()
```

Comment: who doesn't just love Groovy?

Answer (score 2):

In reply to Christoph :
For my use case, I've replaced the block

```
line = reader.readLine()
if (line) {
    c.call(line)
}
else {
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000)
}
```

with

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    c.call(line)
Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000)`
```

`... != null` => to ensure empty lines are outputted as well
`while (...` => to ensure every line is read as fast as possible