# How to read from a dynamic file in Groovy

Tags: file, groovy, recursion, logging

I've got the log file for a program; the log records every task done by the software.  I've modified the software to insert a line such as `"operations terminated"` into the log when the software is done executing.  I am trying to write a script in Groovy that looks for this `"operations terminated"` line in the log file.  I am unsure how to proceed because the log file changes with time and I want to catch `"operations terminated"` as soon as it pops up.  I don't know how to put in a recursive or continuous check...  Suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Here is a Q/A on tailing a file in Groovy. Checking the lines for a specific pattern is an easy extension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905605/tail-a-file-in-groovy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

monitoring may be a solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/495962/722948

So then. you could take the delta of the file and search for a specific line/word