# How to display last part of log file dynamically in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have 3 log files and a selectone Menu.Based on the selection, the last part of any one of the log file needs to be displayed dynamically.Which PrimeFace component will do this and how.

Answer (score 0):

There is no stand alone component for this in primefaces, you should use a few basic principals.

1. Read the last lines of a log file, you may see this question [Java IO implementation of unix/linux "tail -f"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557844/java-io-implementation-of-unix-linux-tail-f)
2. When reading file you should store the lines read to a collection of strings in your managed bean
3. On selection of your selectOneMenu, you should change your filename and regenerate your collection, again on the same managed bean.
4. On ajax complete event of your selectOneMenu ("update" attribute), you should update a jsf display component which links to your collection.

Comment: Hi I managed to do it by reading the last n lines of the file and assigned it to a string.Then using an inputTextArea component of PrimeFaces to display it by setting this String as its value.Now the problem is I want to put a link to the end of this inputTextarea to go to the full log file.I appended some HTML CODE to the end of the string like <html><body><a href="D:\Edgeserverlogs\node2.out">View Full Log</a></body></html>. But it is displaying all the content in same manner I appended, not in HTML link format in  input text Area.how can I give a link to the end of an InputTextArea content.