# java how to read a file in real time

Tags: java, file, time

I am supposed to create a log analysis software for my Master Degree thesis. 
Currently I am in the data collection phase :) so I need a way to read a file in real time.
For example I have to monitor the "/var/log/auth.log" file and to look for failed logins (just an example among the 1000000s to come for my program:) ). So I need to read the file line by line. OK, if I were to use a scripting language (Python, Ruby) this would be really easy, but since I am in JAVA, I wasn't very lucky. Anybody gotta clue how to read a file in Real Time, maybe an example?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to tail the file?

Comment: Exactly, like tail. I've already done some research for this. I could use something like execve with tail, but it would not be useful, because I must call it constantly, and it is impossible to know how many lines were written during calls.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds duplicated to
[Java IO implementation of unix/linux "tail -f"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557844/java-io-implementation-of-unix-linux-tail-f)

And the winner was:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line;
while(true) {
    line = reader.readLine(); // blocks until next line available
    // do whatever You want with line
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to open the file for reading and place directly at the end of the file? This is precisely my problem. I do not know how to place myself at the end of the file,and read the lines to come, starting that moment.