# Read a file that is being written to by another process

Tags: java

I have a file that is being written to by another process (completely different pid). I know it is writing to the file line-by-line.

From Java, I would like to read this file line-by-line as the lines are being written to it. (or as close as I can get to that).

Rather than re-inventing the wheel...is there already a common way to achieve this in Java? It would be nice to have a blocking function called `.readLine()`.

Comment: You mean, you want to synchronize the producer and the consumer? Can you modify the sources of the writer, or isn't it under your control? Have you tried with a filesystem-level watcher? What are the supported OS?

Comment: I think this is quite like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557844/java-io-implementation-of-unix-linux-tail-f - I'd personally prefer the Apache Commons IO way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to observe events from your operating system.

I prefer the option using the [take](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html#take()) method since it prevents your system from polling needlessly and waits for events from your operating system.

I have used this successfully on Windows, Linux and OSX - as long as **Java 7** is available since this is a new feature since JDK 1.7.

Here is the solution I came up with - running in a different thread than the main thread since I didn't want this to block my UI - but this is up to you and your application architecture.

```java
boolean run = true;
WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
Path watchingPath = Paths.get("path/to/your/directory/to/watch");
watchingPath.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

WatchKey key = null;
while(run && !isCancelled()) {
    try {
        key = watchService.take();
        for(WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
            if(!isCancelled()) {
                if(event.context().toString().equals(fileName)) {
                    //Your file has changed, do something interesting with it.
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //Failed to watch for result file cahnges
        //you might want to log this.
        run = false;
    } catch (ClosedWatchServiceException e1) {
        run = false;
    }
    
    boolean reset = key.reset();
    if(!reset) {
        run = false;
    }
}
```

---

#### See Also

- [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) official documentation

Comment: This doesn't answer my question...my question was around the reading of the file....I am making the assumption that I cant read and write to the same file a tame time from different processes - maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Are you in control of the software that writes the file as well?

Comment: I am, but I'd rather not add any extra logic if it can be avoided.

Comment: If your file on your "writer" program is closed, after writes, this code above will get called every time there is a line that is written.  If you file is ALWAYS open on the writer side, then you will need to change this to a polling function that will re-open the file every now and again and get the new changes (that is using this technique).