# how can I read an updating file?

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to read a log file for streaming.Also that file is appending new records.

```
while(true){
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines()) {
    pub.publish(topic, line)}}
```

With this above code it again read file from the beginning . How I can overcome this situation.Next time I want it read from the upcoming records not the entire records

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered here: [Java IO implementation of unix/linux "tail -f"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557844/java-io-implementation-of-unix-linux-tail-f)

I am not familiar with scala, but it seems that the logic is simple and clear enough to convert into scala syntax. Hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

**BufferedReader to the rescue**

I have solved this problem using `java.io.BufferedReader`.

Short solution

```
while (true) {

   if (reader.readLine() != null) {
    //keep reading and pushing the data to function f
    f(reader.readLine())
   } else {
    Try {
     Thread.sleep(checkingTime)
    }
   }//end of if

  }//end of while
```

**More Info**

Lets say `stream.txt` is the file which is getting updated continuously by another process.

Now if we want to read progressively from the file without starting from the start.

The trick is `BufferReader`'s `readLine` method returns `null` when it reaches `EOF`, wait when it gives `null` and start checking if anything is written to the file using `readLine` and the start reading using same `readLine`.

Here is the code snippet for progressive reading.

```
object ProgressiveReader {

 def read(file: File, checkingTime: Long = 1000)(f: String => Unit): Unit = {

  import java.io._

  val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)))

  while (true) {

   if (reader.readLine() != null) {
    //keep reading and pushing the data to function f
    f(reader.readLine())
   } else {
    Try {
     Thread.sleep(checkingTime)
    }
   }//end of if

  }//end of while

}

 //usage
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  read(new File("stream.txt")) { str =>
   println(str)
  }
 }

}
```