# Reading large log files in real time in Java

Tags: java, performance, io

What can I use to read log file in real time in Java 8?
I read blogs to understand BufferedReader is a good option for reading fine. 
 I tried below:

```
BufferedReader reader = new 
BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line;
while(true) {
line = reader.readLine(); // blocks until next line 
available
// do whatever You want with line
}
```

However it keeps printing null irrespective of file is updated or not. Any idea what can be going wrong.

Any other options?

Details are as below : 
I am trying to create an utility in Java 8 or above, where I need to read log file of an application at real time (as live transactions are occurring and getting printed in logs).

I can access log file as I am on sme server, so that is not an issue.

So some of the specifics are below
-> I don't want to poll the log files for Changes, I want to keep it the bridge open to read log file in "while true" loop. So ideally i want to block my reader if there are no new lines getting printed.

-> I don't want to store the entire content of the file in memory at all time as I want it to be memory efficient.

-> my code will run as a separate application to read log file of another application.

-> only job of my code is to read log, match against a pattern, if matched then send a message with log content.

Kindly let me know if any detail is ambiguous.

Any help is appericiated, thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: So it seems you want to tail the file in java, Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557844/java-io-implementation-of-unix-linux-tail-f

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, your `inputStream` must block until new data becomes available, which a standard `FileInputStream` does not when reaching the end-of-file.

I suppose, you initialize `inputStream` to just `new FileInputStream("my-logfile.log");`. This stream will only read to the current end of the log file and signal the "end of file" condition to the `BufferedReader`. This in turn will signal "end of file" by returning `null` from `readLine()`.

Have a look at the utility `org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer`. This allows to write programs like the Unix utility `tail -f`.

To make your code work, you would have to use an "infinite" input stream that could be realized using a `RandomAccessFile` as in the following example:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class TestRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        File logFile = new File("my-log.log");
        // Make sure to start form a defined condition.
        logFile.delete();
        try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(logFile.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE)) {
            // Just create an empty file to append later on.
        }

        Thread analyzer = Thread.currentThread();

        // Simulate log file writing.
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (int n = 0; n < 16; n++) {
                        try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(logFile.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
                            PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(out);
                            String line = "Line " + n;
                            printer.println(line);
                            printer.flush();
                            System.out.println("wrote: " + line);
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    analyzer.interrupt();
                }
            }
        }.start();

        // The original code reading the log file.
        try (InputStream inputStream = new InfiniteInputStream(logFile);) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), 8);
            String line;
            while (true) {
                line = reader.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    System.out.println("End-of-file.");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("read: " + line);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class InfiniteInputStream extends InputStream {

        private final RandomAccessFile _in;

        public InfiniteInputStream(File file) throws IOException {
            _in = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            if (b == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            } else if (off < 0 || len < 0 || len > b.length - off) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            } else if (len == 0) {
                return 0;
            }

            int c = read();
            if (c == -1) {
                return -1;
            }
            b[off] = (byte)c;

            int i = 1;
            try {
                for (; i < len ; i++) {
                    c = readDirect();
                    if (c == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    b[off + i] = (byte)c;
                }
            } catch (IOException ee) {
            }
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            int result;
            while ((result = readDirect()) < 0) {
                // Poll until more data becomes available. 
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        private int readDirect() throws IOException {
            return _in.read();
        }

    }
}
```