# Is it possible to read and write in file at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io

Here's the scenario:

- ThreadA is going to read from some socket, and write data to "MyFile.txt"
- ThreadB is going to read "MyFile", and when it reaches the end, it will loops until new data are available in MyFile (because i don't want to re-open "MyFile.txt", and lose the time so i reach the position from where i was..).

Is it possible to do such a thing ?

If not, is there another way to do such a thing ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use Java to read from a file that is actively being written?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149/how-do-i-use-java-to-read-from-a-file-that-is-actively-being-written)

Comment: I've added a link to a question which is a duplicate of this one. But in passing, have you seen RandomAccessFile? You don't need to go through an entire file again to read from a particular position

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem you mention is a famous [Producer Consumer Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem)

Common solution to this is to use [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

An example of real world usage is in [AjaxYahooSearchEngineMonitor](http://jstock.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jstock/jstock/src/org/yccheok/jstock/engine/AjaxYahooSearchEngineMonitor.java?revision=1.1&view=markup)

What Thread A does is, it will submit a string to queue, and then return immediately.

What Thread B does is, it will pick up the item from queue one by one, and process them.
When there is no item in the queue, Thread B will just wait there. See line 83 of the source code.

Comment: thank you very much !! that's exactly what i wanted. it's better than read/write from DataBase or file.