# Is it possible to disable TimingLogger lines in log file?

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

We are using Cassandra as our database and use Hector to talk to Cassandra.

In our log file there're tons of following lines:

**2015-10-15 08:53:50,798 INFO  m.p.cassandra.hector.TimingLogger - start[1444910030795] time[3] tag[READ.success_]
2015-10-15 08:53:50,798 INFO  m.p.cassandra.hector.TimingLogger - start[1444910030797] time[1] tag[WRITE.success_]**

Speed4j is logging in INFO level and it logs all "hector.TimeLogger" lines. The issue I have is we cannot modify the executable jar file. Therefore, is it possible to find other ways to mute those lines? Or what should we configure/modify if we can modify the source code?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write another Java program that redirects only some lines to another log. You can read a file with an BufferedInputStream while its beeing written.

More information on such a "file redirection" is here: [How do I use Java to read from a file that is actively being written?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149/how-do-i-use-java-to-read-from-a-file-that-is-actively-being-written)

This does not fix the additional lines in log, but you could create a second clean log with it