# Reading from buffers/streams in parallel

Tags: java

I have this program that has 3 processes:

- `P1` - reads data from a file does some processing and writes data to a new file .
- `P2` reads from this file does some processing and writes data to another file.
- `P3` reads data from this file and does some processing and prints an output.

Right now these are sequential but I dont need `P1` to write all the data before `P2` can start reading. So id like to make all 3 processes run in parallel in java. So that as and when `P1` writes a line to the file, `P2` can start reading it and the same for the file that `P2` writes to and `P3` reads from.

**Any ideas how I can implement this in java?**

*Here is an image description of what I'm trying to do:*
 [image: link to image]

Comment: This is far easier to implement in one process. There is no standard way to read a file while it is being written to, you can invent one (which is not as easy as it sounds), or you can just use multiple threads in one process and pass the data via a queue.

Comment: if you are not using the file created by p1/p2 again, why do you need to store it? Just create a pipeline with a queue of strings/lines. If you go through the file system it would become more convoluted

Comment: Sounds like a case where RxJava might be helpful. Making the writer observable and let the reader subscribe to changes.

Comment: I read that Files parallel stream works well.  You can have P1 run in parallel, then P2, then p3.

Comment: If you want to do this correctly, you should not use `Files`, but `Pipes`. Open files have a highly chaotic behavior because of how the OS and cache handle them.

Comment: Looks like this as been answered before. Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32783641/2254148

Comment: I dont have to use files. I dont have much idea about pipes. Could you please guide me to a resource to help me understand how to use pipes in java. Can i use streams or buffers?