# Setting listener for an input stream in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, listener, cpu, inputstream

This is just an example. I have an input stream and I want to set an listener for it. How can I can do it?

The first way is creating a background thread that checks it repeatedly.

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            // Optional sleep to avoid wasting CPU cycles
            int c;
            if((c = in.read()) != -1)
                addEventToUIthread(c);
        }
    }
}
```

But I think without *Thread.sleep*, it will waste CPU cycles.
And with it; it will decrease accuracy to get events.

Assume that the input stream is an file that an inaccessible output stream is writing to it. This is just an example to illustrate that I don't know the amount of runtime cost of such background threads.
What is the explanation?

Comment: does `in.read()` waste cpu cycles while blocking?

Comment: as i said before it's an example you may assume it's just an condition not stream. however a FileInputStream doesn't block thread. it will return -1 at the end of stream.

Comment: Of course it will return something at the end of the stream, otherwise you could never know you've reached the end. But until then, the `read()` method does block the thread. [FileInputStream#read()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read())

Comment: true; it will reach the end of thread very soon and whenever the file grows it will read the new content otherwise repeatedly return -1.

Comment: sorry there's a typo in my last comment , first line. edit "end of file"

Comment: Are you looking for an efficient way to read a file that grows continuously, getting new data as quickly as possible, without wasting too much CPU, or do you just want to know how much CPU is wasted if you don't use `Thread.sleep()` ?

Comment: both. thank you.

Comment: For the efficient way, you first have to define your expectations in terms of smoothness, then find the timing that meets your goals. For the CPU waste, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your program to keep reading a file after it has reached the end, without any pause between attempts, then from the moment the `read()` function returns -1 for the first time, to the moment new data arrives, your program will use all CPU time available, since it will only go back and forth to the `read()` function, which is not a background operation.

The same goes with any other loop containing only foreground operations.

Comment: what's alternative way?

Comment: Judging by this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/154588/17335001), or others to this question, I think everyone ends up doing the same thing : one way or another they introduce a small pause between read attempts. `Thread.sleep()` is not worse than any other way, you should go with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read input bytes immediately, you don't need to use Thread.sleep here to protect CPU cycles, because InputStream.read() method runs synchronously, in other words, it blocks until one byte is available.

However if you want to intentionally slow down CPU usage while reading data, using Thread.Sleep would be the correct way.

Comment: as i said before it's an example you may assume it's just an condition not stream. however a FileInputStream doesn't block thread. it will return -1 at the end of stream